# Склонение слова Табель

Tags: склонение

Табель -  мужского рода. Склоняется как женский. Как правильно -  поварская табель или поварской табель. Имеется ввиду табель о рангах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Табель не склонятся "как женский". Вы своей формулировкой немного заблудились в истории.
Есть два варианта слова - мужского и женского рода, их склонение вполне соответствует грамматическому роду. Т.е. женский род ***табели*** склоняется по женской парадигме, мужской род ***табеля*** - естественно, по мужской.

Во времена Петра табель был женского рода, впоследствии, вплоть до наших дней, по традиции "табель о рангах" сохранила женский род, со всеми вытекающими. Склоняется как карамель или канитель:

И. Петровская "Табель о рангах" 
Р. Петровской "Табели о рангах"  
и т.д.

Про "поварскую табель" я сейчас не соображу, что это такое, но по ощущением - что-то действительно очень древнее, поэтому скорее всего - тоже женского рода и тоже склоняется по парадигме третьего склонения.

Современная же норма: **табель** - мужского рода, склоняется как *учитель* или *выключатель*.